# Apache Beam - Error with example using Spark Runner pointing to a local spark master URL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-beam

I need to support a use case where we are able to run Beam pipelines in an external spark URL.

I took a basic example of a beam pipeline as below

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions


class ConvertToByteArray(beam.DoFn):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def setup(self):
        pass

    def process(self, row):
        try:
            yield bytearray(row + '\n', 'utf-8')

        except Exception as e:
            raise e


def run():

    options = PipelineOptions([
        "--runner=SparkRunner",
        # "--spark_master_url=spark://0.0.0.0:7077",
        # "--spark_version=3",
    ])
    with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
        lines = (p
                 | 'Create words' >> beam.Create(['this is working'])
                 | 'Split words' >> beam.FlatMap(lambda words: words.split(' '))
                 | 'Build byte array' >> beam.ParDo(ConvertToByteArray())
                 | 'Group' >> beam.GroupBy()  # Do future batching here
                 | 'print output' >> beam.Map(print)
                 )
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

I try to run this pipeline in 2 ways

1. Using Apache Beam's internal spark runner
2. Running Spark locally and passing the spark master URL.

Approach 1 works fine and i'm able to see the output (screenshot below)

[Screenshot of Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyJGR.png)

Approach 2 gives a class incompatible error on the spark server
Running spark as a docker container and natively on my machine both gave the same error.
Exception trace

```
Spark Executor Command: "/opt/bitnami/java/bin/java" "-cp" "/opt/bitnami/spark/conf/:/opt/bitnami/spark/jars/*" "-Xmx1024M" "-Dspark.driver.port=62420" "org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend" "--driver-url" "spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@192.168.8.120:62420" "--executor-id" "0" "--hostname" "172.17.0.2" "--cores" "4" "--app-id" "app-20220425143553-0000" "--worker-url" "spark://Worker@172.17.0.2:44575"
========================================

Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
22/04/25 14:35:55 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Started daemon with process name: 165@ace075bc56c0
22/04/25 14:35:55 INFO SignalUtils: Registering signal handler for TERM
22/04/25 14:35:55 INFO SignalUtils: Registering signal handler for HUP
22/04/25 14:35:55 INFO SignalUtils: Registering signal handler for INT
22/04/25 14:35:56 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
22/04/25 14:35:56 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: spark,nikamath
22/04/25 14:35:56 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: spark,nikamath
22/04/25 14:35:56 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
22/04/25 14:35:56 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
22/04/25 14:35:56 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(spark, nikamath); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(spark, nikamath); groups with modify permissions: Set()
22/04/25 14:35:57 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to /192.168.8.120:62420 after 194 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
22/04/25 14:35:57 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: spark,nikamath
22/04/25 14:35:57 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: spark,nikamath
22/04/25 14:35:57 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
22/04/25 14:35:57 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
22/04/25 14:35:57 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(spark, nikamath); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(spark, nikamath); groups with modify permissions: Set()
22/04/25 14:35:57 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to /192.168.8.120:62420 after 19 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
22/04/25 14:35:58 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/spark-41a0e50e-81aa-48b7-ae55-888ae3a0a4ca/executor-a5ff3b34-0166-405f-9c00-d5a5ee6f8688/blockmgr-d7bd5b95-ddb3-4642-9863-261a6e109fc4
22/04/25 14:35:58 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 366.3 MiB
22/04/25 14:35:58 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Connecting to driver: spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@192.168.8.120:62420
22/04/25 14:35:58 INFO WorkerWatcher: Connecting to worker spark://Worker@172.17.0.2:44575
22/04/25 14:35:58 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to /172.17.0.2:44575 after 7 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
22/04/25 14:35:58 INFO WorkerWatcher: Successfully connected to spark://Worker@172.17.0.2:44575
22/04/25 14:35:58 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
22/04/25 14:35:58 INFO ResourceUtils: No custom resources configured for spark.executor.
22/04/25 14:35:58 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
22/04/25 14:35:58 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Successfully registered with driver
22/04/25 14:35:58 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID 0 on host 172.17.0.2
22/04/25 14:35:59 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 39027.
22/04/25 14:35:59 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 172.17.0.2:39027
22/04/25 14:35:59 INFO BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
22/04/25 14:35:59 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(0, 172.17.0.2, 39027, None)
22/04/25 14:35:59 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(0, 172.17.0.2, 39027, None)
22/04/25 14:35:59 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(0, 172.17.0.2, 39027, None)
22/04/25 14:35:59 INFO Executor: Fetching spark://192.168.8.120:62420/jars/beam-runners-spark-3-job-server-2.33.0.jar with timestamp 1650897351765
22/04/25 14:35:59 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to /192.168.8.120:62420 after 5 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
22/04/25 14:35:59 INFO Utils: Fetching spark://192.168.8.120:62420/jars/beam-runners-spark-3-job-server-2.33.0.jar to /tmp/spark-41a0e50e-81aa-48b7-ae55-888ae3a0a4ca/executor-a5ff3b34-0166-405f-9c00-d5a5ee6f8688/spark-cd481993-e8df-46fd-b00c-9a31e17d245d/fetchFileTemp1955801007454794690.tmp
22/04/25 14:36:02 INFO Utils: Copying /tmp/spark-41a0e50e-81aa-48b7-ae55-888ae3a0a4ca/executor-a5ff3b34-0166-405f-9c00-d5a5ee6f8688/spark-cd481993-e8df-46fd-b00c-9a31e17d245d/-16622853561650897351765_cache to /opt/bitnami/spark/work/app-20220425143553-0000/0/./beam-runners-spark-3-job-server-2.33.0.jar
22/04/25 14:36:04 INFO Executor: Adding file:/opt/bitnami/spark/work/app-20220425143553-0000/0/./beam-runners-spark-3-job-server-2.33.0.jar to class loader
22/04/25 14:36:04 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Got assigned task 0
22/04/25 14:36:04 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Got assigned task 1
22/04/25 14:36:04 INFO Executor: Running task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1)
22/04/25 14:36:04 INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
22/04/25 14:36:04 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.spark.util.AccumulatorV2; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 8273715124741334009, local class serialVersionUID = 574976528730727648
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:699)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:2005)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1852)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:2005)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1852)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2186)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2431)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2213)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:503)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:461)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.metrics$lzycompute(Task.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.metrics(Task.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1462)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
22/04/25 14:36:04 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1)
java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.spark.util.AccumulatorV2; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 8273715124741334009, local class serialVersionUID = 574976528730727648
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:699)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:2005)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1852)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:2005)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1852)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2186)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2431)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2213)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:503)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:461)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.metrics$lzycompute(Task.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.metrics(Task.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1462)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
22/04/25 14:36:04 ERROR SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0),5,main]
java.lang.Error: java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.spark.util.AccumulatorV2; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 8273715124741334009, local class serialVersionUID = 574976528730727648
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1155)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.spark.util.AccumulatorV2; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 8273715124741334009, local class serialVersionUID = 574976528730727648
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:699)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:2005)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1852)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:2005)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1852)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2186)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2431)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2213)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:503)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:461)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.metrics$lzycompute(Task.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.metrics(Task.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$collectAccumulatorsAndResetStatusOnFailure$1(Executor.scala:424)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$collectAccumulatorsAndResetStatusOnFailure$1$adapted(Executor.scala:423)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.collectAccumulatorsAndResetStatusOnFailure(Executor.scala:423)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:704)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    ... 2 more
22/04/25 14:36:04 ERROR SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1),5,main]
java.lang.Error: java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.spark.util.AccumulatorV2; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 8273715124741334009, local class serialVersionUID = 574976528730727648
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1155)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.spark.util.AccumulatorV2; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 8273715124741334009, local class serialVersionUID = 574976528730727648
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:699)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:2005)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1852)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:2005)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1852)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2186)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2431)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2213)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1669)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:503)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:461)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.metrics$lzycompute(Task.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.metrics(Task.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$collectAccumulatorsAndResetStatusOnFailure$1(Executor.scala:424)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$collectAccumulatorsAndResetStatusOnFailure$1$adapted(Executor.scala:423)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.collectAccumulatorsAndResetStatusOnFailure(Executor.scala:423)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:704)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    ... 2 more
22/04/25 14:36:05 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
22/04/25 14:36:05 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
22/04/25 14:36:05 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
22/04/25 14:36:05 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-41a0e50e-81aa-48b7-ae55-888ae3a0a4ca/executor-a5ff3b34-0166-405f-9c00-d5a5ee6f8688/spark-cd481993-e8df-46fd-b00c-9a31e17d245d
```

I confirmed that a worker was running and the spark was set up properly.
I submitted a sample spark job to this master and get it to work implying that there isn't anything wrong with the spark master or worker.

Versions used:

1. Spark 3.2.1
2. Apache Beam 2.37.0
3. Python 3.7

Comment: it is not Scala. Why you add Scala/Java tags?

Comment: Removed the tags.

Comment: Your Beam probably uses a different spark version than 3.2.1, try finding out the spark version and use that as your spark

Comment: Any idea where I can find that out. ? I have tried with Spark 2.4.3, 2.4.6 and 3.2.1 and I got the same error although for different classes. The Apache beam documentation mentions that it supports Spark 2.4 onwards.

Comment: As per Beam programming guide, the named functions used in ParDo must be registered in an init block otherwise it will not get executed on distributed runners. Is this something related to that? https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#pardo